# Generate CSR and private key with password with OpenSSL

Tags: cryptography, certificates, openssl, pem

I am using the following command in order to generate a CSR together with a private key by using **OpenSSL**:

```
openssl req -new -subj "/CN=sample.myhost.com" -out newcsr.csr -nodes -sha512 -newkey rsa:2048
```

It generates two files:

- `newcsr.csr`
- `privkey.pem`

The generated private key has no password: how can I add one during the generation process?

**Note:** take into account that my final goal is to generate a `p12` file by combining the certificate provided according to the CSR and the private key (secured with a password).

Answer (score 48, accepted):

## Ditch "-nodes"

If you actually WANT encryption, then you'll need to remove the (awkwardly named) `-nodes` (read: *"**No DES** encryption"*) parameter from your command.

Because `-nodes` will result in an unencrypted privkey.pem file. And if you leave it out, then the file will be encrypted.

So without `-nodes` openssl will just PROMPT you for a password like so:

```
$ openssl req -new -subj "/CN=sample.myhost.com" -out newcsr.csr -sha512 -newkey rsa:2048
Generating a RSA private key
.........................................+++++
................+++++
writing new private key to 'privkey.pem'
Enter PEM pass phrase:
Verifying - Enter PEM pass phrase:
-----
```

But interactive prompting is not great for automation. So if you don't want to be prompted then you might want to read on for how to use "Pass Phrase arguments".

## Use OpenSSL "Pass Phrase arguments"

If you want to supply a password for the output-file, you will need the (also awkwardly named) `-passout` parameter.

This is a multi-dimensional parameter and allows you to read the actual password from a number of sources. Such as from a file or from an environment variable. Or straight from the command line (least secure). Below are examples for each of these usages.

(The official [manpage lists even more password-sources in the *"Pass Phrase Options"* section](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl.html) (Archived [here](https://archive.vn/wip/Z4k9G).))

### Example: password from command line with "pass:"

```
$ openssl req -new -passout pass:"Pomegranate" -subj "/CN=sample.myhost.com" -out newcsr.csr -sha512 -newkey rsa:2048
Generating a 2048 bit RSA private key
................................................................................................................................+++
......................+++
writing new private key to 'privkey.pem'
-----


$ openssl rsa -in privkey.pem -passin pass:'Pomegranate' | head -n2
writing RSA key
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEpQIBAAKCAQEAsSP5kLRPP8wPODrnvuAeeoqGMqTOvRULL423vv6+zjYhwPUi
```

### Example: password from variable with "env:"

```
$ export MYPASS='Elderberry'


$ openssl req -new -passout env:MYPASS -subj "/CN=sample.myhost.com" -out newcsr.csr -sha512 -newkey rsa:2048
Generating a 2048 bit RSA private key
............................+++
.....................+++
writing new private key to 'privkey.pem'
-----


$ openssl rsa -in privkey.pem -passin pass:'Elderberry' | head -n2
writing RSA key
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEpQIBAAKCAQEAv0NnBnigPp+O9G4UXc0qSyeELdJJjTmnO9GEtE5GlPGoK7vW
```

### Example: password from file with "file:"

```
$ echo "Farkleberry" > password.txt


$ openssl req -new -passout file:password.txt -subj "/CN=sample.myhost.com" -out newcsr.csr -sha512 -newkey rsa:2048
Generating a 2048 bit RSA private key
......................+++
...........+++
writing new private key to 'privkey.pem'
-----


$ openssl rsa -in privkey.pem -passin pass:'Farkleberry' | head -n2
writing RSA key
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEpAIBAAKCAQEAsHICgYvqe4i9CIR5eQk38JJmuTaJQvyxPH9S+BahT5XWh88z
```

## Related Reading

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4294689/how-to-generate-an-openssl-key-using-a-passphrase-from-the-command-line

Comment: LOL, so that's what **nodes** stands for. Guessing that option preceded both **asn1-kludge** and **set_serial**

Comment: Whether password will or will not be asked for depends on some config options in the defaults somewhere. To force it you have to select the cipher. Unfortunately I didn't yet see any discussion of which to choose, all examples simply blindly throw in `-des3`.

Answer (score 3):

You can update the key with a password with the following command:

`openssl rsa -des3 -in server.key -out server.key.new`

Then use `mv server.key.new server.key` to ovewrite the old key.